# Why does the Collection interface have equals() and hashCode() when we can directly use methods from Object Class

Tags: java, collections, equals, hashcode

Why does the `Collection` interface have `equals()` and `hashCode()` when we can directly use methods from `Object` class... why again?

Comment: Because the implementations in the `Collection` API have different semantics.

Comment: The two exist only to for documentation purposes, so that the general contract for all Collections is specified there.

Comment: @Kayaman, the interface doesn't change the default implementation, and the answer you linked to is not the same question as this..

Comment: @xs0 you're right, I'll reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You’re thinking of terms of compilation.  Java SE is an object-oriented library;  methods are defined as part of a *contract,* not just to declare methods available to other code wen compiling.

[Collection.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) refines the contract of Object.equals with additional stipulations:

> The general contract for the `Object.equals` method states that equals must be symmetric (in other words, `a.equals(b)` if and only if `b.equals(a)`). The contracts for `List.equals` and `Set.equals` state that lists are only equal to other lists, and sets to other sets. Thus, a custom `equals` method for a collection class that implements neither the `List` nor `Set` interface must return `false` when this collection is compared to any list or set.